# Use applicationsetting.json for settings in BotFramework v3

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

Hi i've a problem with botframework v3 (.Net 4.6), i need to transfer the part applicationsetting present in the web.config into a new file applicationsettings.json.
I use a singleton object on the Global.asax for take all the settings from this json file, and it works.
I see a problem when i debug my bot because it go in exception when i call the PostAsync.
Before some test i understand the problem, the bot search in my web.config MicrosoftAppId and the MicrosoftAppPassword but i have this values into the new file.
My questio is:

There's the possibility to change the bot settings from the web.config into a new json file completly?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the variables need to be in AppSettings for Autofac to find them.

You can though add them in after reading them from your Json file: we do this in the controller constructor (we have different config sections for different bots)

```cs
AddConfigurationSetting("MicrosoftAppId", appId);
AddConfigurationSetting("MicrosoftAppPassword", appPassword);

private static void AddConfigurationSetting(string name, string value)
{
    if (!ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains(name))
    {
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name] = value;
    }
}
```